# AttributeError: 'HTTPMessage' object has no attribute 'getparam'

Tags: django, parsing, python-3.6

I use python3 version in Ubuntu.

The code I use could run in python 2.7 version.

But I got some of Import Errors and Attribute Errors in python 3.

I want to edit this code for 3.6 version.

But I can't find any document for Attribute Error trouble shooting.

The error message I got is as below :

```
taylor@taylor-Rev-1-0:~/taylor/pyBook/ch2$ python parse_image.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "parse_image.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
File "parse_image.py", line 28, in main
    charset = f.info().getparam('charset')
AttributeError: 'HTTPMessage' object has no attribute 'getparam'
```

and the methods or classes I imported is shown as below :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from html.parser import HTMLParser
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
charset = response.headers.get_content_charset()
```

you can use this in python3

Comment: It works! thanks.                " $ python parse_image.py

>>>>>>>>>>> Fetch Images from http://www.google.co.kr
/textinputassistant/tia.png   "